# ArcGIS API for JavaScript: Graphic does not display in IE10

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, arcgis-online, web-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have recently created an application using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. The application contains a geocoding functionality in which a point graphic is supposed to display showing the matching address. This is what the working result looks like in Google Chrome:

[image]

However, when the application is being used in IE 10, the point graphic does not show up upon successful completion of the geocoding operation (a match score of greater than 80). Here is what it looks like after geocoding in IE 10:
[image]

I have used the 'SimpleMarkerSymbol' to create the marker symbol for the 'Graphic' that is returned from the geocoding operation. Is this some sort of known issue that occurs when using ArcGIS API for Javascript graphics in IE?